intellij run http request from anywhere
With intellij when I'm debugging, in console or anywhere I'd like to throw again a http request I did run with one operation (or the few possible). The only ways I found are

take my mouse and go from debug to services, and click on the particular request
go to the same with keyboard shortcut if that's even feasable
run anything (2x ctrl) doesnt work as it requests me to specify the environment again

